# Implementing the same feature on two app versions

Tags: android, android-studio, code-duplication

I have two versions of an app (paid and free). When I add a new feature in both versions I have to write the same code on both of them. Is there a way to write the code on one of them and then add automatically on the other? Or at least set a point from which to start marking the code lines changed to add it later on the other version?

Comment: Create an android module and import itvia gradle

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Android app that will act as a core. Both the paid and the free apps would use it. Everything that's using the same code should be moved into the core app and only the differences should remain in the free and the paid apps, respectively.